What medieval(?) movie features a scene in a wooden multilevelled marketplace/naval office/stock market or similar?

Country: I would say American
Year: The release must have been somewhere in the 90s - my best bet is 96-98 at some point. Might be later. 

Reason I am so interested in this movie, is because it gave me a really cozy-adventurous fairytale feel - it's hard to describe, but it's the kind of movie you would enjoy on a rainy day or close to ie. XMAS.
I only remember this one scene. 

I remember it giving me a cozy feeling, which leads me to believe it is kind of an adventure movie. A group of people (possibly involving young adults or even kids) being in this "marketplace" filled with people, selling things I think. There is a lot of mess here and a very important thing is the fact that I think it is multi levelled, meaning that it s shaped as a square with a hole in the middle, showing a similar squared floor beneath with kind of the same marketplace-action going on. 
I don't remember who stars in it
It gave me an impression that the setting is medieval, pirate-y or in some way "back in time" - meaning there is no electronics or anything, but there might be some supernatural things going on. 
It seemed like there is a group of "main characters" that for some reason had to talk to someone in this wooden marketplace. 


Any more details? Like the kind of clothes, or hair style, or what supernatural things?

Kind of clothes: I'd have to say maybe renascence? Again, it's a vague childhood memory I am trying to bring back, so it might be pirate-themed, but my best bet would be something similar to I.E. master and commander. What really imprinted itself in me, was the surroundings. This dark wood building, 3-4 stories with a hole in the middle. Supernatural things, I don't know, I am not 100% sure of this, I just have a feeling there might be some magic in the movie, like Hook or Peter Pan or something, but I ain't too sure. Don't remember hairstyles :(

Thanks, and you remember something from the plot?

I am afraid not, I was rather young. I know it's not much to go on. My best guess is some sort of "quest".
